How to adjust the formatter in VSCode to avoid unnecessary line breaks?
I think 'Visual Studio Code' is applying too strict formatting rules that sometimes lines are moved even if there is enough space on the right side.
For starters, if you look at 'ProfileImage', you can see that it is formatted as a single line with the 'child' property and that's ok.
But why does it move the line after the 'crossAxisAlignment' property ? (where the question mark is in the picture).
How to adjust the formatter to avoid unnecessary line breaks?


I resolved the issue by adjusting the VSCode settings. The Dart: Line Length was set to 80, but changing it to 120 solved the problem.
